# How to collect multiple format arguments in C language?

Tags: c, scanf

I have the following code where I'm asking the user to input a string 'towers' followed by integers. When I try to scanf the data inputs give the following:
[image]

This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>   
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
int n, from, dest;
char code[]= "towers";


printf ("Code?");
scanf ("%c ", &code);

printf ("Code?");
scanf ("%d %d %d", &n, &from, &dest);


if (strcmp(code,"towers")==0 && n==0){
n=3;
from = 1;
dest = 2;
    if (argc > 1){ 
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    }
    towers(n, from, dest);
    exit(0);
}
else{
printf ("nothing\n");
printf ("%d",n);
}
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is check user input if they type 'towers' just by itself or if they type 'towers' followed by a set of three other integers. thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html

Comment: Compile with `-Wall`. Let the compiler show you the error of your ways.

Comment: `scanf ("%c ", &code);` --> `scanf ("%6s", code);`

Comment: Why is it that after the first scanf ("%c", &code) is executed the second scanf is completely skipped and the code continues to the if-statement?

Comment: That is because c is the format specifier for character input. Use '%6s' for your input as suggested.Then the second scanf wont be skipped.

Answer (score 4):

```
char line[80];
int a, b, c;
fgets(line, 80, stdin);

if (sscanf(line, "towers %d%d%d", &a, &b, &c) == 3)
    /* read in towers and three ints */
else if (strcmp(line, "towers") == 0)
    /* read in towers */
```

Comment: i tried it your way but its not recognizing when the user inputs "towers" without the integers. So the else if part of the statement does not run.